# OpenGL doesn't render triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I have been trying to get OpenGL working, but for some weird reason, the triangle isn't being rendered. I have checked everything, vertex, fragment shader, the code, but didn't find any issue. The screen is being cleared, but the triangle isn't being rendered. I am following Official Guide to learning OpenGL version 4.3 by Dave Shreiner, Graham Sellers, John Kessenich, Bill Licea-Kane, Eighth edition.
Necessary informations:

OS: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera

(from glxinfo)

OpenGL vendor string: AMD

OpenGL renderer string: RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-75-generic)

OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5

OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60

OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)

OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL core profile extensions:

compilation command: `g++ main.cpp LoadShaders.cpp -L/usr/lib64 -lGLEW -lGL -lX11 -lGLU -lSDL2 -llua5.4 -o exec`

main.cpp

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include<GL/glxew.h>

#include "LoadShaders.hpp"

namespace Tutorial
{
    SDL_Window* window=nullptr;
    SDL_GLContext context=nullptr;
    GLuint va;
    GLuint buffer;
    GLuint Program;
}

bool InitGL()
{
    const float vPosition[6][2]={
        {-90.0f,-90.0f},
        { 0.85f, -0.90f },
        { -0.90f, 0.85 },
        { 0.90f, -0.85f },
        { 0.90f, 0.90f },
        { -0.85f, 0.90f }
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&Tutorial::va);
    glBindVertexArray(Tutorial::va);
    glGenBuffers(1,&Tutorial::buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Tutorial::buffer);
    glBufferData(0,sizeof(vPosition),vPosition,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    if(!LoadShaders(&Tutorial::Program))
    {
        return false;
    }

    glUseProgram(Tutorial::Program);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    
    return true;
}

bool Init()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to initialize SDL2: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else if(SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,4) || SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,6) || SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK,SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to set attribute: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else if(!(Tutorial::window=SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL tutorial",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,512,512,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to create window: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else if(!(Tutorial::context=SDL_GL_CreateContext(Tutorial::window)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to create OpenGL context: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else if(GLenum glinit_ret; (glinit_ret=glewInit())!=GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to initialize glew: %s\n",glewGetErrorString(glinit_ret));
        return false;
    }

    return InitGL();

}

void Render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(Tutorial::va);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);
    glFlush();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(Tutorial::window);
}

void Fini()
{
    if(Tutorial::Program)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(Tutorial::Program);
    }


    glUseProgram(0);
    glDeleteProgram(Tutorial::Program);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glDeleteBuffers(1,&Tutorial::buffer);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&Tutorial::va);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(Tutorial::window);
    SDL_Quit();

}


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(Init())
    {
        printf("Successfully initialized\n");
        SDL_Event event;
        bool running=true;
        glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        while(running)
        {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if(event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    running=false;
                }
                else if(event.type==SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_ESCAPE)
                {
                    running=false;
                }
            }

            if(!running)
                break;
            Render();
        }
    }

    Fini();
    return 0;
}
```

LoadShaders.cpp

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include<GL/glxew.h>
extern "C"
{
    #include<lua5.4/lua.h>
    #include<lua5.4/lauxlib.h>
}
#include "LoadShaders.hpp"

const char* errmsg[8]={"GL_INVALID_ENUM","GL_INVALID_VALUE","GL_INVALID_OPERATION","GL_STACK_OVERFLOW",
"GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW","GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY","GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION","GL_CONTEXT_LOST"};

const char* GetError(int errtype)
{
    if(errtype>=0x0500)
    {
        return errmsg[errtype-0x0500];
    }
    return nullptr;
}

bool CompileShaders(GLenum shader_t,const char* source,GLuint* shader)
{
    if(shader)
    {
        const char* Typename;
        switch(shader_t)
        {
            case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
            {
                Typename="Vertex Shader";
                break;
            }
            case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
            {
                Typename="Fragment Shader";
                break;
            }
            case GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER:
            {
                Typename="Geometry Shader";
                break;
            }
        }

        *shader=glCreateShader(shader_t);
        if(*shader==0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to create %s: %s\n",Typename,GetError(glGetError()));
            return false;
        }

        glShaderSource(*shader,1,&source,nullptr);

        if(GLenum retval=glGetError();retval==GL_INVALID_VALUE || retval==GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"glGetError(): %x\n",retval);
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to load source for %s: %s\n",Typename,GetError(retval));
            fprintf(stderr,"printing the source: %s\n",source);
            glDeleteShader(*shader);
            *shader=0;
            return false;
        }

        glCompileShader(*shader);
        GLint status;
        glGetShaderiv(*shader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
        if(status==GL_FALSE) //if compilation failed
        {
            //get the error msg
            glGetShaderiv(*shader,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&status);
            GLchar* logmsg=new GLchar[status];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader,status,nullptr,logmsg);
            glDeleteShader(*shader);
            *shader=0;
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to compile %s: %s\n",Typename,logmsg);
            delete[] logmsg;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool LoadShaders(GLuint* pptr)
{
    
    if(pptr)
    {
        if(GLenum errret; (errret=glewInit())!=GLEW_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to do glew initialize: %s\n",glewGetErrorString(errret));
            return false;
        }

        //get the source string
        lua_State* state=luaL_newstate();
        if(!state)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to create new lua state\n");
            return false;
        }

        if(luaL_loadfile(state,"VertexShader.lua") || lua_pcall(state,0,1,0))
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to load file VertexShader.lua: %s\n",lua_tostring(state,-1));
            lua_close(state);
            return false;
        }

        char* vs_source=new char[strlen(lua_tostring(state,-1))];
        if(!vs_source)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to allocate memory for Vertex Shader source\n");
            lua_close(state);
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(vs_source,lua_tostring(state,-1));

        if(luaL_loadfile(state,"FragmentShader.lua") || lua_pcall(state,0,1,0))
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to laod file FragmentShader.lua: %s\n",lua_tostring(state,-1));
            delete[] vs_source;
            lua_close(state);
            return false;
        }

        char* fs_source=new char[strlen(lua_tostring(state,-1))];
        if(!fs_source)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"failed to allocate memory for Fragment Shader source\n");
            delete[] vs_source;
            lua_close(state);
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(fs_source,lua_tostring(state,-1));

        lua_close(state);

        //get the shader compiler do the compilation
        GLuint vshader,fshader;
        if(!CompileShaders(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vs_source,&vshader) || !CompileShaders(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fs_source,&fshader))
        {
            delete[] vs_source;
            delete[] fs_source;
            return false;
        }
        delete[] vs_source;
        delete[] fs_source;

        *pptr=glCreateProgram();
        if(*pptr==0)
        {
            glDeleteShader(vshader);
            glDeleteShader(fshader);
            return false;
        }

        glAttachShader(*pptr,vshader);
        glAttachShader(*pptr,fshader);

        glLinkProgram(*pptr);
        glDetachShader(*pptr,vshader);
        glDetachShader(*pptr,fshader);

        glDeleteShader(vshader);
        glDeleteShader(fshader);

        GLint status;
        glGetProgramiv(*pptr,GL_LINK_STATUS,&status);
        if(status==GL_FALSE)
        {
            glGetProgramiv(*pptr,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&status);
            GLchar* logmsg=new GLchar[status];
            glGetProgramInfoLog(*pptr,status,nullptr,logmsg);
            glDeleteProgram(*pptr);
            *pptr=0;

            fprintf(stderr,"failed to link program: %s\n",logmsg);
            delete[] logmsg;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

VertexShader.lua

```
return [[
#version 460 core
layout(location=0) in vec4 vPosition;
void main()
{
    gl_Position=vPosition;
    gl_Position.z=0.0;
    gl_Position.w=1.0;
}
]]
```

FragmentShader.lua

```
return [[
#version 460 core
out vec4 fcolor;
void main()
{
    fcolor=vec4(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
}
]]
```

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return anything? Also maybe https://renderdoc.org/ might be of use. Also, this is quite a strange use of Lua.

Comment: I thought I may need to do some rigorous shader writing in future, so I setup loading sources in this way, but even I think fread is better, might change later. 
As for glGetError(), not it's not returning anything relatable. I tried to do a glGetError() after the glDrawArrays() too, but no value was returned.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I also checked renderdoc's result. But no luck. renderdoc doesn't record any error, and capture result is same. Frames are rendered correctly, however no triangle isn't being rendered yet. I tried out changing glClearColor() value to white, red and others, but its still the same. The window is cleared, but no triangle.

Comment: Have you taken a look to where the triangle get rastered on the screen, where is culling done, is the z-buffer check is okay? I think renderdoc tells you all of that.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I checked the capture result again, it seems like it really does the rendering, when a frame is captured, but when I see it in the window, the triangle isn't rendered at all.

Comment: It's not going to do any automatic error reporting. I would start with the "Mesh view" -> "VS in" and "VS out" to see the mesh as it comes into the vertex shader and out of it. Since we already know the answer, it would've shown no mesh there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of [`glBufferData`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) specifies the target to which the buffer object is bound:

<s>`glBufferData(0, sizeof(vPosition), vPosition, GL_STATIC_DRAW)`</s>

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vPosition), vPosition, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`glBufferData` creates and initializes a buffer object's data store for the specified traget.
When [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is associated to the specified attribute index and the ID of the object is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO.